# cluster using feature hashing

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have to cluster some documents that are in json-format. I would like to tinker with feature-hashing to reduce the dimensions. To begin small, here is my input:

```
doc_a = { "category": "election, law, politics, civil, government",
          "expertise": "political science, civics, republican"
        }

doc_b = { "category": "Computers, optimization",
          "expertise": "computer science, graphs, optimization"
        }
doc_c = { "category": "Election, voting",
          "expertise": "political science, republican"
        }
doc_d = { "category": "Engineering, Software, computers",
          "expertise": "computers, programming, optimization"
        }
doc_e = { "category": "International trade, politics",
          "expertise": "civics, political activist"
        }
```

Now, how do I go about using feature hashing, create vectors for each document and then compute similarity and create clusters? I am a bit lost after reading http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html.
 Not sure if I have to use "dict" or convert my data to have some ints and then use 'pair' for 'input_type' to my featureHasher. How should I interpret the output of featureHasher? For example, the example http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html outputs a numpy array.

```
In [1]: from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

In [2]: hasher = FeatureHasher(n_features=10, non_negative=True, input_type='pair')

In [3]: x_new = hasher.fit_transform([[('a', 1), ('b', 2)], [('a', 0), ('c', 5)]])

In [4]: x_new.toarray()
Out[4]:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.]])

In [5]:
```

I think the rows are documents and column values are ..? Say, if I want to cluster or find similarity between these vectors (using Cosine or Jaccard), not sure if I have to do item-wise comparison?

expected output: doc_a, doc_c and doc_e should be in one cluster and the rest in another cluster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll make things easier on yourself if you use the `HashingVectorizer` instead of the `FeatureHasher` for this problem.  The `HashingVectorizer` takes care of tokenizing your input data and can accept a list of strings.

The main challenge with the problem is that you actually have two kinds of text features, `category` and `expertise`.  The trick in that case is to fit a hashing vectorizer for both features and then combine the output:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import hstack
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

docs = [doc_a,doc_b, doc_c, doc_d, doc_e]

# vectorize both fields separately
category_vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
Xc = category_vectorizer.fit_transform([doc["category"] for doc in docs])

expertise_vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
Xe = expertise_vectorizer.fit_transform([doc["expertise"] for doc in docs])

# combine the features into a single data set
X = hstack((Xc,Xe))
print("X: %d x %d" % X.shape)
print("Xc: %d x %d" % Xc.shape)
print("Xe: %d x %d" % Xe.shape)

# fit a cluster model
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2)

# predict the cluster
for k,v in zip(["a","b","c","d", "e"], km.fit_predict(X)):
    print("%s is in cluster %d" % (k,v))
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I tried it on 10 documents with 4 kinds of text-features and it worked well. Now, I can visually look into the members of a cluster and see what features contributed to its "closeness". As I work on very large datasets, this becomes a problem as the document says : "there is no way to do inverse transform (from feature indices to string feature names) which can be a problem when trying to introspect which features are most important to a model."). I am looking at other things that sklearn can offer. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, there's a tradeoff with HashingVectorizer in that you can fit your model with many more features but you lose the ability for introspection.  The other vectorizers in sklearn (CountVectorizer, TFIDFVectorizer) will allow you to perform introspection but they have a much bigger footprint; to fit them on large data sets you can set max_features to a reasonable number.

Comment: If I have to manually compute the similarity between two hashed-vectors (the feature vector which contains the count of hashes in each feature-bucket) - I can simply use jaccard or cosine I believe. right?